# Why am I getting "Cannot read property 'text' of undefined" in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oop

I'm in the progress of making a game, which you can by clicking [here](http://playclassicsnake.com/play). My first question is why I'm getting

> Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

when the snake (green blocks) hits the food (red circle).

The line that is invoking the error is the `this.scoreElem.text(newScore);` from

```
function StatHandler ( totalScoreSelector, fruitEatenSelector )
{
    this.scoreElem = $(totalScoreSelector);
    this.fruitEeatenElem = $(fruitEatenSelector);

    this.incrementScore = function ( incAmount )
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Play/IncrementScore?amount=" + incAmount,
            success: function (newScore)
            {
                this.scoreElem.text(newScore);
            },
            error: function ( ) 
            {
                alert("error occured!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The instance of a `StatHandler` object is created by

```
var H = new StatHandler("#total-score", "#fruit-eaten");
```

inside a `$(document).ready`, where I've verified that `#total-score` and `#fruit-eaten` are valid selectors since they are `id`s of elements I've verified to be in the DOM.

Full code can be seen [here](https://github.com/jamkin/Snake/blob/master/SnakeGame/Scripts/game.js).

Also, as you may have noticed, I'm trying to update the score on the server side and send the updated score back to the client. But, this doesn't prevent the client from cheating by running

```
SG.stats.incrementScore(1000000000);
```

in the JS console. How do I prevent cheating?

Comment: I assume, that’s because `this` inside the `success` function doesn’t refer to whatever `this` refers to outside of it. Therefore, `this.scoreElem` is undefined.

Comment: Xufox is right. Add `var me = this;` right before the ajax call and use `me.scoreElem.text` instead of `this.scoreElem.text`

Comment: @Xufox Thanks. That helped.

Comment: Because this refers to the window/xhr object, but not to the object you want it to.

Comment: Please refrain to posting one question at a time. Your post isn't an ongoing debug thread. Post another question if you ran into other problems. This one is about the undefined property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment your `this` keyword isn't referring to the object you want it to. It's bound to the scope of the success function. So `this.scoreElem` is undefined. Calling `text` on undefined will raise an error.

```
function StatHandler ( totalScoreSelector, fruitEatenSelector )
{
    this.scoreElem = $(totalScoreSelector);
    this.fruitEeatenElem = $(fruitEatenSelector);

    this.incrementScore = function ( incAmount )
    {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Play/IncrementScore?amount=" + incAmount,
            success: function (newScore)
            {
                self.scoreElem.text(newScore);
            },
            error: function ( ) 
            {
                alert("error occured!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Referring `this` via `self` will get it to work. Since JavaScript uses lexical scoping, the variable `self` will be available when the ajax success function is parsed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `context` property of `$.ajax` options to set what `this` is within the callbacks if you don't want it to be the settings object.

```
this.incrementScore = function ( incAmount )
    {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            context: this, // set callback context
            url: "Play/IncrementScore?amount=" + incAmount,
            success: function (newScore)
            {
                this.scoreElem.text(newScore);
            },
            error: function ( ) 
            {
                alert("error occured!");
            }
        });
    }
```